# Moment.js time format error

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have following where

```
moment(13:00:00,'ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ').format('HH:mm');
```

I'm expecting 13:00, but i keep getting 5:45 which is GMT I guess.

Also,

```
moment(13:00:00,'ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ').format('HH:mm am');
I should get 1:00am but O'm getting 5:45am.
```

Solved the issue by doing following

```
moment(13:00:00,"hh:mm a").format('hh:mm a');

moment(13:00:00,"HH:mm").format('HH:mm');
```

Answer (score 1):

The input string requires quotes around it.

Also, the format you pass should match the data.

```
moment("13:00:00","HH:mm:ss").format("HH:mm")
```